# Hive: substract one table from another?

Tags: sql, join, hive, difference

In Hive I have two tables:

```
'old_books' 
 title String, author String, year Int, outOfPrint Boolean;
```

and

```
'new_books'  
title String, author String, year Int;
```

By some mistake those who created these tables have put some new titles into 'old_books' table.

Is it possible to substract records that exist in both tables from 'old-books' table by means of Hive only?

So far I have only manged to select books that exist in both tables with Hive request:

```
SELECT old_books.* FROM old_books JOIN new_books ON (old_books.title=new_books.title);
```

How to substruct result of this request from 'old_books' ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in 'substruct'? What you want to get in result?

Comment: I need to remove records that have the same name in both tables from 'old-books'

Comment: Depends, which version of hive do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Hive 01.3 version or later, you can use not exists clause:

select * from old_books a where not exists (
SELECT 1 FROM old_books b JOIN new_books c ON (b.title=c.title)
where a.book_id = b.book_id);

Here is the reference:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works for me:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE corrected_old_books
SELECT old_books.* FROM old_books left JOIN new_books ON (new_books.title=old_books.title) where new_books.title is NULL;
```

I use /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.13.0.2.1.3.0-563.jar